# wordpress multisite password reset sub domain redirect to same url issue

Tags: php, wordpress

After trying to reset password wordpress multisite sub domain(e.g sub.example.com), it redirects user to main website(e.g example.com instead of sub.example.com) 
I found a plugin here that seems solved problem for some people but I'm getting this error:
The email could not be sent.
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.

Note:It works without this plugin but having redirect to main site, it means reset password function works fine without using this plugin but to solve url redirection to related subdomain I'd like to use this plugins so after activating the plugin

PHP 7.0.25
Wordpress multi site version: 4.9.1-0
Server: Debian 9
Mail: SendGrid

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you want to fix the redirect or the mail() error? Or both?

Comment: @Kapparina both

Comment: what is the plugin you are using?

Comment: @Brett https://gist.github.com/eteubert/293e07a49f56f300ddbb